# Reduzir o tamanho de uma imagem e manter a proporção com CSS

Tags: css, imagem

Se tenho uma imagem horizontal (320x205),

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="imagem.jpg" width="320" height="205" />
</div>
```

e coloco a regra CSS `.container img { max-width: 200px; }`, a redução não fica proporcional:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

E se coloco `{ max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px }` dá errado com imagens horizontais e verticais. Como acertar isso?

```css
.container img {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height:250px;
}
.container {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
img {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<h2>Imagem horizontal</h2>
ORIGINAL: <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/Zacharias_Wagner_-_Mameluca.jpg" width="320" height="205">
<div class="container">MAX-WIDTH: <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/Zacharias_Wagner_-_Mameluca.jpg" width="320" height="205" /></div>

<h2>Imagem vertical</h2>
ORIGINAL: <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/Docteur_Piron_-_La_Bonite.JPG" width="241" height="400">
<div class="container">MAX-WIDTH: <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/Docteur_Piron_-_La_Bonite.JPG" width="241" height="400" /></div>
```

Comment: Boa. Fiquei com a impressão de que isso já foi perguntado, mas não consegui achar a suposta duplicata.

Comment: @bfavaretto, pois é, juro que procurei uma duplicata...

Comment: Acho que o mais próximo é isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26003 (+ a resposta do utluiz). Porém a sua pergunta é tão mais simples e objetiva, que prefiro manter como canônica.

Comment: Tinha visto essa. Sim, o troço é complicado lá. E como não vi nada falando do `auto` nem de `max-*`....

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Falta o valor [`auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Values) para o `width` e `height`. Assim a escala é feita conforme largura ou altura (o que atingir primeiro) e a proporção é feita automaticamente.

```
.container img {
    max-width:200px;
    max-height:150px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

```css
.container img {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height:250px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.container {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
img {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<h2>Imagem horizontal</h2>
ORIGINAL: <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/Zacharias_Wagner_-_Mameluca.jpg" width="320" height="205">
<div class="container">MAX-WIDTH: <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/Zacharias_Wagner_-_Mameluca.jpg" width="320" height="205" /></div>

<h2>Imagem vertical</h2>
ORIGINAL: <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/Docteur_Piron_-_La_Bonite.JPG" width="241" height="400">
<div class="container">MAX-HEIGHT: <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/Docteur_Piron_-_La_Bonite.JPG" width="241" height="400" /></div>
```

Comment: Declarar o valor `auto` seria redundante, já que são valores padrões.

Comment: @Meuovo eu concordo sobre parecer redundante mas nos meus testes só funcionou com `auto` junto.

Answer (score 20):

'Solução' usando JQuery: Substitua o elemento `IMG` por um outro que suporte background, como `DIV`. Passe o valor de `src` para `background-image`, assim como os valores de largura e altura da tag `IMG` original:

```
$('.container img').replaceWith(function(i, v){
    return $('<div/>', {
        style: 'background-image: url(' + this.src + ');' + 
        'width:' + this.width + 'px;' + 
        'height:' + this.height + 'px;' ,
        class: 'fakeImg'
    })
})
```

Ajuste o valor da propriedade `background-size` para `cover`, e ajuste o posicionamento para centralizado:

```
.container .fakeImg {
    background: no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;    
}

.container
{
    display:inline-block;
    border:2px solid red;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

Com isso, você terá um elemento DIV falso que permite o corte proporcional da imagem para que ela se encaixe exatamente nas dimensões indicadas no elemento `IMG` original:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Exemplo no Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/7z3z8z94/7/).

Comment: Interessante, mas a imagem fica com 100x100px e perde a proporção...

Comment: @brasofilo eu atualizei o exemplo - a proporcão é mantida sim, pode verificar. =)

Comment: Ah, rapaz, seu truque faz um *crop*! Cool :))

Comment: @brasofilo mais uma atualizaçãozinha no JSFiddle pra deixar mais claro. Checa lá!

Comment: bom mesmo isso, grande técnica :D

Answer (score 14):

No CSS existe ainda a propriedade [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) que define como um objeto deve se comportar perante um elemento com dimensões definidas. Para efeito de exemplo, vamos considerar um elemento quadrado com 100 px de lado e uma [imagem](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_PKF6UPtmhk/maxresdefault.jpg) com 1280x720 px.

A propriedade pode receber diversos valores:

- **`fill`**, preenche todo o elemento com o conteúdo da imagem, mantendo as dimensões definidas para o elemento, não a proporção da imagem;

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_PKF6UPtmhk/maxresdefault.jpg">
</div>
```

- **`contain`**, preenche todo o elemento com a maior dimensão da imagem, adaptando a menor dimensão conforme a proporção original;

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_PKF6UPtmhk/maxresdefault.jpg">
</div>
```

- **`cover`**, preenche todo o elemento com a menor dimensão da imagem, adaptando a maior dimensão conforme a proporção original, ocultando o conteúdo da imagem que excede as dimensões do elemento;

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_PKF6UPtmhk/maxresdefault.jpg">
</div>
```

- **`none`**, preenche o elemento com a imagem em seu tamanho original, ocultando o conteúdo que excede as dimensões do elemento;

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_PKF6UPtmhk/maxresdefault.jpg">
</div>
```

- **`scale-down`**, a imagem será adaptada à sua menor versão entre os resultados de `none` ou `contain`;

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_PKF6UPtmhk/maxresdefault.jpg">
</div>
```

---

O [suporte à propriedade `object-fit`](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit) é relativamente alto, com exceção à família IE/Edge:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem completo o exemplo! Obrigado pela contribuição!

Comment: Muito bom isto! Só estou na dúvida do porquê o  `img { }` está definido com 100x100px no CSS, o `object-fit` vai considerar aquilo como a área a ser preenchida? Nesse caso, qual o motivo do `div` *container* também ter 100x100px?

Answer (score 4):

Eu geralmente configuro somente o width no css.

```
.container img {
    max-width:300px;
    width: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fxuvnfah/

Answer (score 4):

Plugin ImgLiquid:
https://github.com/karacas/imgLiquid

Recursos:

- Usa as informações de background-size do CSS
- Compatível com Bootstrap
- Tamanho reduzido < 2KB (gzip)
- Fill / Crop
- Responsivo
- Suporte Svg
- Callbacks
- Atributos HTML data-*
- Todos os navegadores (Inc. ie6)

Answer (score 1):

Briguei bastante com este problema. Genericamente a solução é meter o img dentro de um div, e limitar apenas a **largura** do div que contém a imagem. A imagem deve ter "width: 100%". Assim, a imagem ficará proporcional, e com a largura do div.

Esse div container deve ter a largura bem definida, pode ser tanto em pixels quanto em porcentagem, mas tem de haver uma largura.

Segue o meu CSS, eu uso dois div's, um dentro do outro, por motivos que vou descrever mais abaixo. O div mais externo (cartimg) tem largura de 55% da página e centraliza graças ao "margin: auto", mas você poderia usar float ou outro método de posicionar o div.

```
#body div.cartimg {
        margin: auto;
        width: 55%;
        text-align: center;
}

#body div.cartimg div.cartimg2 {
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding: none;
}

#body div.cartimg img {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0em;
        margin-top: 0em;
        margin-right: 0em;
        margin-bottom: 0em;
}
```

Um problema adicional que enfrentei foi o seguinte: eu tenho imagens de diferentes larguras e alturas, e gostaria de limitar o tamanho da imagem nas duas dimensões. Uma imagem larga pode ocupar 55% da largura, mas uma imagem muito estreita seria "esticada" para cobrir os 55% e ficaria compridíssima no sentido vertical. Isso é particularmente desagradável numa tela mobile.

Uma solução é mudar manualmente o tamanho da imagem (width menor que 100%), outra é recalcular usando Javascript (dinamicamente), a solução que eu adotei foi calcular a proporção da imagem no PHP e alterar a **largura** do container cartimg2 de modo a limitar sua **altura**, se a imagem for mais alta que 16:9. (As tentativas de limitar diretamente a altura não deram muito certo.)

Segue o código PHP relevante:

```
function get_container_width($addr)
{
        $tallest = 16.0 / 9.0;

        $container_width = 100;

        if ($addr[0] == '/') {
                $addr = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $addr;
        }

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($addr);
        if ($width > 0 && $height > 0) {
                $prop = $width / $height;
                if ($prop < $tallest) {
                        // image is 'tall', or thin
                        // we need to limit width to limit height indirectly
                        $container_width *= $prop / $tallest;
                }
        }

        return $container_width;
}

    $container_width = get_container_width($addr);

    echo("<div id='$name' class=cartimg>");
    echo("<div id='hdiv_$name' style='width: $container_width%;' class=cartimg2>\n");
    echo("<a href='$addr' class=noarrow>\n");
    echo("<img src='$addr' alt='$desc'>\n");
    echo("</a>\n");
    echo("</div>");
    echo("<i>$desc</i>\n");
    echo("</div>");
```

A solução usando background image em vez de img também funciona para limitar altura e largura, só que aí você está jogando a semântica Web fora (o Google acha as imagens pelo tag img, e suas descrições pelo atributo alt).

Answer (score -1):

simples..

você limiita a largura que quer no máximo como 100% da div em que a imagem está contida.. e a altura você coloca como auto !important;

exemplo:

```css
#apresentacao-texto-loop img {width:100%;height:auto !important;}
```

sempre coloco assim e redimensiona proporcionalmente ;)

Answer (score -2):

Você pode definir o tamanho mínimo e máximo como iguais, assim a imagem terá sempre a mesma proporção. Por exemplo:

```
.give-wrap .give-card__media img {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
object-fit: cover;
order: 1;

    max-width:300px;
    max-height:300px;
    min-height:300px; 
    min-width:300px;
width: auto;
height: auto;
```