# Como organizar fotos em vários quadros

Tags: html, css

Eu queria fazer esse efeito da imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjSzL.jpg)

```css
img.fotosC {
  margin: 5px;
}

img.fotoLat {
  width: 17%;
}

img.fotoCent1 {
  width: 10%;
}

img.fotoCent2 {
  width: 40.5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="ContCentral">
  <div>
    <img class="fotoLat fl fotosC" src="https://rolfmodas.com.br/PCP/_fotos/716E-1.jpg" /> <!--class fl é "float left"-->
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="fotoCent1 fotosC" src="https://rolfmodas.com.br/PCP/_fotos/006E-1.jpg" />
    <img class="fotoCent2 fotosC" src="https://rolfmodas.com.br/PCP/_banner/1-banner.png" /></br>
    <img class="fotoCent2 fotosC" src="https://rolfmodas.com.br/PCP/_banner/4-banner.png" />
    <img class="fotoCent1 fotosC" src="https://rolfmodas.com.br/PCP/_fotos/2000P-1.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="fotoLat fotosC" src="https://rolfmodas.com.br/PCP/_fotos/015-1.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jovem isso muito provavelmente foi feito com display:grid do css... se quiser eu faço um exemplo básico pra vc

Comment: Quero sim, nunca ouvi falar nesse display

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara como vc falou que não conhece o `display:grid` vou te sugerir esse guia completo vai te ajuda até em outros casos.

Agora veja essa imagem, repare nas linhas do grid eu dividi elas usando `repeat(nomero de repetiçoes, tamanho da célula)` no caso 8 células de tamanho igual `repeat(8, 1fr)`, para fazer o tamanho das células eu usei span n / n, vc pode ler sobre isso aqui tb: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column e para dar o espaçamento entre uma imagem e outra basta setar o `grid-gap` (deixei comentado no css)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja a responsividade natural do `grid`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sobre o ajuste das imagens dentro da célula eu usei `object-fit` vc pode ler mais sobre isso nessa pergunta: [Reduzir o tamanho de uma imagem e manter a proporção com CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32936/reduzir-o-tamanho-de-uma-imagem-e-manter-a-propor%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-css)

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    height: 200px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100px);
    grid-gap: 1rem; /* espaço entre as imagens */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.i1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.i2 {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
.i3 {
    grid-column: 4 / 7;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
.i4 {
    grid-column: 7 / 9;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.i5 {
    grid-column: 3 / 6;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
.i6 {
    grid-column: 6 / 7;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

section {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid;
}
section > img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <section class="i1">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
    </section>
    <section class="i2">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
    </section>
    <section class="i3">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
    </section>
    <section class="i4">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
    </section>
    <section class="i5">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
    </section>
    <section class="i6">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Aeee !! Consegui adaptar tudo certinho, obrigadão. Usarei o `display: grid` mais vezes

Comment: @GabrielArcuri rapaz eu estava lendo o comentário aqui rss

Comment: @GabrielArcuri mas que bom que resolver, se vc acha que o problema foi resolvido considere marcar a Resposta como Aceita **✓** assim ela não fica pendente no site como pergunta sem resposta aceita