# Redimensionar imagens celular

Tags: css

Tenho uma página de post, que recebe essa configuração para as imagens que vem do banco de dados:

```
.post-content img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

O que acontece é que, ao ver a foto no celular, elas ficam alongadas, meio deformadas, alguém conhece alguma maneira de redimensioná-las mas mantendo o mínimo do padrão dela de visualização?

Comment: Amigão, não sei se está usando bootstrap, mas dentro do bootstrap existe o img-responsive

Comment: Isso deve te responder: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32936/reduzir-o-tamanho-de-uma-imagem-e-manter-a-propor%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-css

Comment: eu estou recebendo as imagens dinamicamente, do ck editor 4, então eu quero apenas aplicar a configuração às imagens, mas elas já vem com uma classe setada do editor, como posso fazer?

Comment: @gabrielfalieri img-responsive do Bootstrap é justamente colocar width:100% e heigt:auto nas imagens, a mesma coisa que ele já tem...

Comment: vou adiocionar o heigt:auto, e ver se ele resolve!

Comment: o problema é que as imagens pareciam deformadas

Comment: Daniel crie um novo .css e indexe ele por último no seu documento, depois que já tiver indexado todos os .css indexe esse novo .css, nele crie uma classe com o mesmo nome da classe que está vindo do banco e nessa classe "reverta" ou zere o valor das propriedades que vc não deseja fazendo um override dessas propriedades. LEIA os links marcados que vc consegue resolver ai

Comment: muito obrigadoo! vou tentar as dicas e envio o feedback!

Comment: Tente adicionando também um `width: 100%;`

Comment: Não funcionou assim Sam

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32936/reduzir-o-tamanho-de-uma-imagem-e-manter-a-propor%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-css


a solução desse link funcionou, mas existe uma maneira de eu aplicá-la apenas nos celulares?

Comment: Sim, colocando dentro de uma regra @media scree and (max-width:768px) { .classe{ seu css} } ... Procure por "media querie css" no google

Comment: RESOLVIDO AMIGOS!! Valeu o suporte!!!

vou deixar aqui o trecho do CSS pra quem desejar resolver algo do tipo:






<style>
 
.post-content img{
 max-width:100%;
}

</style>

<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) 
{
  .post-content img
   {
  
 max-width:300px;
    max-height:350px;
   width: auto;
    height: auto;
   }
}
</style>